# With JavaScript pinned Element on Website jumps and has an enourmous delay when scrolling

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, fixed, sticky

I'm building a custom wordpress menu navigation bar thats located after a Slider that fills the whole viewport. Said bar is supposed to stick to the top when you scroll past it.
 
The Theme being used is "Holmes - Digital Agency" from Mikado + revolution slider. 
The Site in question is https://www.level-7.de if you wanna have a look for yourself, right now the scrollmagic-version is active since it's working the best out of all three versions.

Important to note here it works fine on Mozilla but not on Chrome or Safari. I tried to implement the pinning with jquery, jscript and scrollmagic. All of these worked atleast for the pinning part. With jquery and jscript there is a massive delay and jump of the element when you scroll. 
With scrollmagic it works fine, except that it almost never works on the first scroll after reloading the page, after that it works perfectly fine. 
Additionally i would want to do it in pure jscript since loading an entire lib for just one effect seems a bit overkill to me.
I tried everything i could find either on here or on scrollmagics github but nothing worked so far.
 I want to make clear again that the pinning does work it's really only that weird delay or just straight up ignore that i don't get. Thanks in advance for any answers that might help me.

Scrollmagic

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({});

  var navpin = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      duration: 0,
      triggerElement: '#start',
      triggerHook: 0   
  });

  controller.addScene(navpin);
  // navpin.addIndicators();
  navpin.setPin("#start");
```

jquery

```
 var main = function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();

        if ( scrollVal >= $('#start').outerHeight(true)) {       
            $('.sticky').css({'position':'fixed','top' :'0px'});
        } else {
            $('.sticky').css({'position':'absolute','top':'auto'});
        }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(main);
```

jscript

```
// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("start");

// Get the body
var bodymargin = document.body;

// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.getBoundingClientRect().top;

// Add the sticky class to the navbar when you reach its scroll position. Remove "sticky" when you leave the scroll position
window.onscroll = function() {
  // console.log(window.pageYOffset);
  // console.log(sticky);
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
    bodymargin.classList.add("bodymargin");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
    bodymargin.classList.remove("bodymargin");  
  }
};
```

some CSS, note that not everything is used for every version

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }

.bodymargin{
    margin-top:100px;
  }

#start{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100px;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 91, 127);
  }
```

In the end it's supposed to look like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp, real smooth and no jumping.

Comment: One thing i forgot to mention: I know i could put the divs position to sticky but that doesn't work with overflow:hidden which is set by the theme. I tried doing a workaround with that but it's an ugly fix and is messing up the site.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It helps getting answers if you provide sufficient informatIon to reproduce the problem in the question itself - if the link dies or is updated to something else it won't help readers in the future. (See the help center for details).  Regarding the issue, you might be interested in [sticky positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) .  Note that providing scroll effects using window scroll events has problems that I discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48246396/5217142)  written in Jan '18

Comment: @traktor53 Thanks for the warm welcome and the provided links. I already tried sticky positioning and it works but not without breaking the themes with the changes i needed to implement to make it work. I'm aware of the problems with window scroll events but used it before without these extreme problems. Also i'm just curious why scrollmagic doesn't hit that first scroll but works fine afterwards. Thank you for your input nonetheless.